# Automatic object mutation Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, binding, mutation

I have a little problem.
I'm working with Vuex and I have a "user" status of object type that when I call this from my component and assign it to the model that I have everything works fine, but when making a change in the model I automatically mutate to my been "user", which I do not want this to happen.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3AIS.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can connect vuex state to v-model with computed's set and get.
In the get you should write a function that returns the desired data from the store.
In the set you should write a function that commits a mutation to the store.

[vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html)  encourage deveolopers to handle forms this way.

```
{
  template : '<input v-model="username"',
  computed: {
   username: {
    get: function () {return this.$store.user.name},
    set: function (newVal) { this.$store.commit('setNewName', newVal)}
    }
  }
}
```